# Cypress task .then don't work as expected

Tags: task, cypress

I've got a problem and I need help to understand what happens. This piece of code works normally :

```
tfc.logout()
            .then(() => {
                cy.log('Before account affectation');
                cy.task('createTestAccount')
                    .then((acc) => {
                        cy.log(acc);        <-- acc is not empty
                        account = acc;
                        expect(account.id).to.exist;
                    });
            });
```

But this one (which should be the same in my understanding don't work) :

```
tfc.logout()
            .then(() => {
                cy.log('Before account affectation');
                return cy.task('createTestAccount');
            })
            .then((acc) => {
                cy.log(acc);             <---- acc is null
                account = acc;
                expect(account.id).to.exist;
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it can help : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Promises

Comment: Thank's it is exactly what I need. I just have to clearly understand the concept now.